# Строгое кол-во объектов на странице

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

доброе время суток. Есть необходимость на странице отрисовать в строку(строка примерно 25-30px в высоту) 30 элементов(объектов). Строго 30, вне зависимости от размера экрана. Кто чем поможет и куда гуглить. объектом является изображение 25px на 25px, если будет подгоняться размер изображения, тем лучше. Не знаю что может помочь организовать, css или js. Заранее благодарю.

P.S 
объектов на странице около 4к

Comment: 30 тэгов img в коде, не понял в чем проблема xD

Comment: объектов на странице около 4к, суть что надо в строку выводить строго 30 элементов)

Comment: Надо как-то подробнее написать, про этот "объект изображения"

Comment: а что именно подробное указать? имеется div с множеством img, он адаптивен и поэтому они автоматически выстраиваются в грубо говоря сетку и там взависимости от размера экрана они либо большие становятся и их мало(5-6 штук) либо их просто больше становится в строку. А мне надо чтобы в строку выходило строго 30 элементов

Comment: Можно сделать js который будет вставлять clearfix после каждого 30 элемента

Comment: не думаю, что это то самое, что я ищу

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/159252)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему подсказали в другом месте. Все решилось одним свойством:

```
img {
  max-width: calc(100%/30);
  min-width: calc(100%/30);
}
```